# How to make facebook FQL query response in XML format?

Tags: facebook-fql

How to make facebook FQL query response in XML format?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to have set your API Client's mode to XML.  By default, it is responding in JSON these days (and the PHP client converts that to a PHP Array) but if you look at the [API Test Console](http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php), you will see you can set the response mode of the client from XML, JSON, and what the PHP client returns.